# Timed Shutdown Using Visudo

Tags: regex, unix, shutdown, sudoers

I am wanting to grant user `user01` on my machine the ability to shut down the machine, but only with no less than 1 hour notice.

Essentially, this boils down to the following command:

`shutdown -h +<time>`

In this case, `<time>` must be greater than 60 (minutes).

Using visudo, I added the following sudoers line:

`user01  ALL=/sbin/shutdown -h +<time>`

I need some way to ensure that `user01` may only issue the halt shutdown if the time argument is greater than 60. I've tried regex, but to no avail. I may be wrong in saying this, but it appears that the sudoers file may not support regex?

Any help with regards to evaluating an expression to achieve this task would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even **want** to know if sudoers has regex support (a quick grep suggests it doesn't):

1. Regexes are tricky, a simple mistake could allow a user to run Elvis-knows-what...
2. [6-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]*[0-9][0-9] - you could shorten it if the notation allows shortcuts for counting occurrences (or just use a '+'), but would you really want it?

That being said, imho the easiest (and most sensible) solution is to write a script along the lines of

```
#! /bin/sh
test $# -eq 1    || exit
test 60 -lt "$1" || exit # maybe print a message
exec /sbin/shutdown -h "+$1"
```

and allow user01 to sudo that script.